# Automatically Add Register Bundles in AppKernel using Composer and post-install-cmd?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, composer-php

I've seen this and currently trying to implement this as an option:

- [Is there a way to update automatically the AppKernel in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082254/is-there-a-way-to-update-automatically-the-appkernel-in-symfony2)

But has anyone ever used Composer to Automatically Register a Bundle in AppKernel using the post-install-cmd option?

So after I install a bundle:

```
composer require Project/ProjectBundle:1.*
```

So in composer.json I might add something like this

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Project\\Bundle\\ProjectBundle\\Composer\\RegisterBundle::registerBundleName"
    ]
},
```

Open to other ideas, thoughts, suggestions as well

Comment: I created https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6082 to discuss the topic.

Comment: @Seldaek Awesome! In your proposal could we run a series of post install commands? checkIfBundleIsRegistered, checkInstalledFormat ( look for zip ), unregisterBundle, registerBundle, makeConfig, makeRouting, makeWhatnot? or am I way off here?

Comment: Way off I am afraid ;) I really think with hooks you're gonna have troubles because stuff will attempt to register itself even when it (sometimes) should not. Automation is not always a good thing.