# Symfony - Console - Enable bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7, symfony-console

Is there any console command to enable an existing bundle ?

- I'm running Symfony 2.7.2
- the bundle files & folders are already here
- it's a custom bundle, no dependencies thought composer

I'm searching for a command **to prevent the user to open himself the appkernel.php file** and add the line.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official command to do that, but i saw a topic where a guy created one for this purpose. 
May be you could try it :

> [Is there a way to update automatically the AppKernel in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082254/is-there-a-way-to-update-automatically-the-appkernel-in-symfony2)

Moreover, there is a github discussion on this subject :

> https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6082

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it's not the most perfect solution I was searching for but it's a good trick to know !